# Django. ListView. The image attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, django, image

I'm new to Django, and I try to show the images of my model via the ListView class but keep getting the error "attribute has no file associated with it".

Below is my code.

model.py:

```
from django.db import models

class AboutModel(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    person_position = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    person_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='team_pictures', blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
from django.views import generic
from . import models

class AboutPage(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'team_list'
    model = models.AboutModel
```

app's urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'app_main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('products_page/', views.ProductsPage.as_view(), name='products_page'),
    path('about_page/', views.AboutPage.as_view(), name='about_page'),
    path('contacts_page/', views.ContactsPage.as_view(), name='contacts_page'),
]
```

project's urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='index'),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('details/', include('app_main.urls', namespace='app_main')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

html:

```
<div class='container team_members'>
    {% for member in team_list %}
        <img src={{ member.person_photo.url }}>
        <br>{{ member.person_name }} - {{ member.person_position }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Solutions to similar issues on stackoverflow didn't help as custom function views are used there or the problem itself is different.

Comment: Always post the whole error message with full traceback.

Comment: I can only guess that all objects don't have an image. If so, in your html put an if statement.

Comment: @AlexDotis, you were right. It turned out one of the added people didn't have a picture. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple - one of users didn't have a picture:)